# OSX Lion: different views in fullscreen and in windowed mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fullscreen

I'm trying to make it so that a certain view contained in a window becomes the main content view when fullscreen mode is toggled and goes back to taking just a portion of the window when the user leaves fullscreen mode.

I've come up with the following:

```
- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"entering fullscreen");
    oldView = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView];
    [oldView retain];
    [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] setContentView:myViewOfInterest];
}

-(void)windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] setContentView:oldView];
}
```

However this only works for the first bit: the window maximises and the view of interest becomes the only one, but when fullscreen mode is left, the view that was the only one visible in fullscreen mode is no longer in the window.

I'm very new to Objective-C and Cocoa, so could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can only be a sub-view to one other view at a time. Your `myViewOfInterest` is removed as a sub-view (of the view hierarchy) of `oldView` when you make it the contentView of the window. When you later restore `oldView` you need to add `myViewOfInterest` back where it was (and what size it was etc.).